# Taking the partial derivative of substitution variables with trig-functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, polar-coordinates, substitution

I have an exercise in mutivariable calculus where I am to transform a function $u(x,y) = u(\rho, \varphi)$ from and to polar coordinates by expressing 
$\partial u/\partial \rho$ and 
$\partial u/\partial \phi$, in order to invert the derived expression and then express
$\partial u/\partial x$ and
$\partial u/\partial y$.

From polar coordinates we have
$$
\begin{cases}
x = \rho \cos{\varphi}\\
y = \rho \sin{\varphi}.
\end{cases}
$$

So, from this, I use the chain rule to express $\partial u/\partial \rho$ and $\partial u/\partial \varphi$ as
$$
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial \rho} = \cos{\varphi}\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \sin{\varphi}\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}\\
\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial \varphi} = 
-\rho\sin{\varphi}\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x} + 
\rho\cos{\varphi}\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}.
\end{cases}
$$
Then I want to do the same thing for $\partial u/\partial x$ and $\partial u/ \partial y$, so by the chain rule I work with the following:
$$
\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x} = 
\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial \rho}\dfrac{\partial \rho}{\partial x} + 
\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial \varphi}\dfrac{\partial \varphi}{\partial x}
$$
and 
$$
\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y} = 
\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial \rho}\dfrac{\partial \rho}{\partial y} + 
\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial \varphi}\dfrac{\partial \varphi}{\partial y}
$$
I use the inverse of the variables $x$ and $y$ to get $\rho$ and $\varphi$, resulting in
$$
\begin{cases}
\rho = \dfrac{x}{\cos{\varphi}} = \dfrac{y}{\sin{\varphi}}\\
\varphi = \arccos{\frac{x}{\rho}} = \arcsin{\frac{y}{\rho}},
\end{cases}
$$
in order to differentiate them with respect to $x$ and $y$ and get the previously unknown 
$$
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{\partial \rho}{\partial x} = \dfrac{1}{\cos{\varphi}}\\
\dfrac{\partial \varphi}{\partial x} = \dfrac{-1}{\rho \sqrt{1-(x/\rho)^2)}} \\
\dfrac{\partial \rho}{\partial y} = \dfrac{1}{\sin{\varphi}}\\
\dfrac{\partial \varphi}{\partial y} = \dfrac{1}{\rho \sqrt{1-(y/\rho)^2)}}
\end{cases}
$$

which I had hoped to plug into the equations and have the solution, but the answer is apparently the following:
$$
\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x} = 
\cos{\varphi}\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial \rho} -
\dfrac{\sin{\varphi}}{\rho}\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial \varphi}
$$
and 
$$
\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y} = 
\sin{\varphi}\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial \rho} + 
\dfrac{\cos{\varphi}}{\rho}\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial \varphi}.
$$

I have no idea how they arrive at this answer. Am I doing something incorrectly? Have I missed a trick somewhere? Or is perhaps the answer to the exercise incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

You have :
$$\begin{pmatrix}\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial \rho}\\
\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial \varphi}  \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} \cos{\varphi}&\sin{\varphi}\\
-\rho\sin{\varphi}&
\rho\cos{\varphi}\end{pmatrix} \cdot\begin{pmatrix}\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}\\
\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}  \end{pmatrix} $$
and:
$$\begin{pmatrix} \cos{\varphi} & \sin{\varphi}\\
-\rho\sin{\varphi}& \rho\cos{\varphi} \end{pmatrix}^{-1}=\frac{1}{\rho}\begin{pmatrix} \rho \cos{\varphi}&-\sin{\varphi}\\
\rho\sin{\varphi}&
\cos{\varphi}\end{pmatrix} $$

Comment: Okay, that works! So that's cool. Just wondering... shouldn't my method work also? I think I have done exactly like that on other problems where the functions were simpler.

Comment: The problem is you method is that you need too express $\rho$ and $\varphi$ as function of $x$ and $y$, but you have expressed in function of $x,y,\rho$ and $\varphi$. To give an example from:
$$\rho=\frac{x}{\cos(\varphi)}$$
you have:
$$\frac{d \rho}{dx}=\frac{1}{\cos(\varphi)}+x\color{red}{ \frac{d\varphi}{dx}} \frac{\sin(\varphi)}{\cos(\varphi)^2}$$
because $\varphi$ and $x$ are not independents.

Comment: But the idea is correct :-). With $\rho=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ , you obtain:
$$\frac{d\rho}{dx}=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$
and:
$$\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\cos(\phi)$$

Comment: This is quite obvious when I think about it. Good explanation! ^^

Answer (score 1):

After you compute $$
\pmatrix{u_{\rho}\\u_{\phi}}=\pmatrix{\cos\phi&\sin\phi\\-\rho\sin\phi&\rho\cos\phi}\pmatrix{u_x\\u_y},
$$
just invert the matrix.